# How to convert PointCloud2 message to a grid?

Tags: ros, lidar, point-cloud

I'm using a Velodyne sensor which publishes on `/velodyne_points` topic, and its class type is `PointCloud2`.

Now I want to convert `PointCloud2` message into a grid space (cylindrical) instead of spherical space. In other words, I want to maps/project Velodyne points (3D) to a grid/panoramic-view (2D) with a const resolution, which each grid cell has a range. Also, this grid's height is const too.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a coordinate transformation. You could make a node that takes in a pointcloud2 message and outputs a message with the data in a cylindrical format.

This website has a thorough overview of what's needed:
https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/12%3A_Vectors_in_Space/12.7%3A_Cylindrical_and_Spherical_Coordinates